# Dynamicly created panels location distance

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm beginner in programming and I want to create a little "game" with `Panel`s.
(Later maybe I'll change for `PictureBox`, but for now it's OK)

Code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int size = 20;
    int quantity = 10;

    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int y = 0; y < quantity; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < quantity; x++)
        {
            Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(
              rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256)
            );

            Panel panel = new Panel
            {
                Size        = new Size(size, size),
                Location    = new Point(x * size, y * size),
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                BackColor   = randomColor
            };

            Controls.Add(panel);
            //panel.Click += Panel_Click;
        }
    }
}
```

I have **two** questions:

- How can I set `5` pixel distance to each `Panel` from each other?
- Should I place these panel creation in the *constructor*? I see people prefer that.

Comment: You can add you Panels (or whatever) to a TableLayoutPanel or FlowLayoutPanel (depending on what kind of layout you're looking for). Note that the `Margin` property of a Control determines the distance from other Controls (it creates a sort of *invisible* external border).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include additional `5` pixels `padding` into `Location`:

```
 ...
 int padding  =  5;
 ... 
 Location = new Point(x * (size + padding), y * (size + padding))
 ...
```

Let's extract a method:

```
 private void CreateGameField() {
   int size     = 20;
   int padding  =  5;
   int quantity = 10;

   Random rnd = new Random();

   for (int y = 0; y < quantity; ++y)
     for (int x = 0; x < quantity; ++x) 
       new Panel() {
         Size        = new Size(size, size),
         Location    = new Point(x * (size + padding), y * (size + padding)),
         BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
         BackColor   = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256)), 
         Parent      = this, // instead of Controls.Add(panel);
       };
 }
```

Then

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {   
   CreateGameField();
 }
```

`FromLoad` event handler is a good place to create the game field; if you want you can place `CreateGameField()` in the constructor, but put it *after* `InitializeComponent()`:

```
 public Form1() {
   InitializeComponent();

   CreateGameField(); 
 }
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted! :) Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why ++y insted y++? I know the difference, but not seeing the benefit here. I'm beginner though :D

Comment: @Lev: it's my old `C` habbit; in time of old (when complier was a tiny 32 kB program on 4 MHz PC) `++x` (increment `x`, return it) was a faster and shorter option than `x++` (store x, increment `x` and return stored `x`). Now both `x++` and `++x` are the same thanks to modern optimizing compilers